# AWS SQS issue. The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I'm facing the following issue.

My application wants to use two AWS SQS queues which are in the same region. My Applications running on EC2.

- is there problem to have two AWS SQS queues in the same user & same region ?
- When i try to connect from EC2 then it says ***"com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.QueueDoesNotExistException: The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue; Request ID: e10c43db-e5db-5143-9"***
- I did try to connect with the same credentials from local environemt. It was able to connect and push the messages to the Queue.
- My AWS User has SQS Full Access, even though it says Queue doesn't exist.

Thanks

Comment: In case you haven't figured it out, please double-check that the account number, the region, and the queue name (case-sensitive) are exactly what they are supposed to be. The case-sensitivity is where I always seem to have a problem.

Comment: Thanks. Code is working after restarted the pods.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/2843

Comment: If you are trying to delete a message using a ReceiptHandle of a non existent message, you will receive this error too. Very Confusing

Comment: Also make sure that the RegionEndPoint you specify for the client object in your code is correct and is the same that you have coded in the URL.

Comment: You might look at this answer once: - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77046729/12326605

Answer (score 0):

According to the original poster in the comments above:

> "Code is working after restarted the pods."